ERR_CONNECTION_RESET but only for certain websites
I have read other questions and answers on this but don't seem to find anything specific to what is happening to me. There is a bit of background to this which I'm not sure is relevant or not so I will detail it below.
I changed mobile network and had some problems with the SIM, had to turn on and off airplane mode multiple times a day to reset internet etc. Someone from their team reset something in the background of my phone to try to help, which reset everything and disconnected not only my data but my Bluetooth connections too? I'm not sure what this means?! My problems still existed no matter what issues they "resolved" in the background.
I finally said I would try a new SIM from the same network in case any of the settings they had changed had messed with the SIM and now it will no longer work.
I activated the new SIM yesterday and have noticed that for some reason there is a certain genre of website that I cannot access and I have used these sites multiple times. They are sites about pregnancy, babies, motherhood etc. Very random!
Initially I was getting the following message when trying to access these websites: ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH.
I contacted my browser which is Ecosia (ran by Microsoft edge) and followed their steps. After following these steps, I am now receiving this error code instead: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET and again only for these websites.
The websites do not work in other browsers either. Any other website I click into works perfectly so I find it to be very unusual. In other browsers I still get the original error code but ecosia now has this new one. I do not care if I can't access it on other browsers so just looking to correct the error code in the title!
All other uses of the internet work perfectly too such as Gmail, social media apps, other web pages, medical device apps, banking apps etc.
With the first SIM my data was reading 5g but with the new SIM it is reading 4g. Apologies, but I don't know if this is relevant!
I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this or have any information that may be useful. It is frustrating that my network doesn't seem to know anything about this and I would like to get it fixed.

Questions about mobile phones are out of scope. If I were to hazard to guess your issue is directly associated with using a non-standard Browser. Ecosia is based of Chromium not Edge, but the error, is legitimate associated with the TLS certificate of the website not matching which ciphers the device supports

Thank you @Ramhound Does this website not answer questions about phones or am I just in the wrong thread? Ah they must have changed it, it used to say Microsoft Edge at the bottom of the screen. These specific websites don't work on any browser, I have tired multiple different ones. Weird tech things always happen me  thank you for answering

This almost sounds like someone is MITM proxying the sites - this seems to me to not be an IP issue as much as an SSL/HTTPS negotiation thing.  What happens if you hotspot the phone - does the laptop/desktop browser work as expected?    Can you have a look at the certificates related to sites that work and don't?

This is indeed usually due to TLS issues. Ive seen this happen due to several reason, mainly because of bad DNS settings or Time settings. Since swapping SIM cards, have you turn your phone off and on again (i know, i know ...) ? I would start there, followed by checking for OS and app updates.
